# Place elements on(not append) the dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use JavaScript to dynamically create a line.  Then I do not know how to place two balls on the 1/3 of length to the beginning and 1/3 of length to the end.  Please see the picture below.  **I want two balls showing up when I press enter in the input box.**  I tried to use append but clearly this did not work.  The code below is the html, css, js code.  Hope someone could help me out.  Thank you in advance.

[image]

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="code.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code_js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "output">

    </div>

    <div id = "user">
        <input type="text" id="input"><br><br>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.deco {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 120px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}


#output {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
}

.line {
    width: 125px;
    height: 80px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#user {
    position:relative;
    z-index:99;
    top:50px;
}

#ball{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #000000;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    make();
    $("#input").keyup(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            //$('#hr1').css("border-bottom-color", "red");
            /*how to put the ball on the line*/
        }
    });
});

function make() {
    var one = document.createElement('div');
    one.className = "line";
    var hr = document.createElement('hr');
    hr.className = "deco";
    hr.id = "hr" + 1;
    one.append(hr);
    $('#output').append(one);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modified your code as per requirement.

No need of div with class `line`.
If you want balls to be appended from js, you can include them in js.

I Hope this helps you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    make();
    $("#input").keyup(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            $('#hr1').css("border-bottom-color", "red");
            $('.ball').css("display", "inline-block");
        }
    });
});

function make() {
    var hr = document.createElement('hr');
    hr.className = "deco";
    hr.id = "hr" + 1;
    $('#output').prepend(hr);
}
```

```css
.deco {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}


#output {
    position: relative;
    width: 125px;
}


#user {
    position:relative;
    z-index:99;
    top:50px;
}

.ball{
    display: none;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #000000;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    z-index: 100;
}
.first-ball {
    left: calc(33.3% - 10px);
}
.second-ball {
    right: calc(33.3% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id = "output">
        <div class="ball first-ball"></div>
        <div class="ball second-ball"></div>
</div>

<div id = "user">
  <input type="text" id="input"><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Suresh, thank you for helping me.  I apologize for not making the question clear enough.  I want two balls showing up when I press enter in the input box.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you Suresh.